# Mail not sending with PHPMailer over SSL using SMTP

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to use PHPMailer to send e-mails over SMTP but so far have had no luck. I've gone through a number of SO questions, PHPMailer tutorials and forum posts but still cannot get it to work. I'll document as many of my failed attempts as I can remember to save time, but firstly here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','On');

    require('includes/class.phpmailer.php');
    include('includes/class.smtp.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $guests = $_POST["guests"];
    $time = $_POST["time"];

    $message = "<h1>".$name." has booked a table for ".$guests." at ".$time."</h1>";

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "myEmail@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "myPassword";        // SMTP account password
    $mail->SetFrom('myEmail@gmail.com', 'James Cushing');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("myEmail@gmail.com","James Cushing");
    $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";
    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
    $mail->MsgHTML($message)
    $address = "myOtherEmail@me.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "James Cushing");

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
?>
```

Firstly, when I run this code now I get two different errors. On my local server I get the error:
**SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Operation timed out (60)

The following From address failed: myEmail@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

Mailer Error: The following From address failed: myEmail@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected**

I get moreorless the same error running the same code on my web server, but the first line is:
**SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)**

Obviously it's worth pointing out that I'm not using the literal "myEmail@gmail.com" but I've substituted my own email out for this post.

**Things I've tried**
 - Using the iCloud SMTP server
 - Using a different port
 - Enabling the OpenSSL extension in my php.ini file
 - Copying code from various PHPMailer examples
 - Using Google's "DisplayUnlockCaptcha" system to enable connections
 - Sending to and from different addresses
 - Removing the "@gmail.com" from the Username property
 - A number of other things I can't remember

This has now been driving me mad for about a day, so if anyone can solve it they will be a hero.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you change port to 465?

Comment: @userNOID That's one of the things I forgot to mention I tried. It gives me this:  

**SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server:   
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:   
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server:   
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected**

Comment: Supports your account SMTP?

Comment: @userNOID Yeah I have it running through MacOS Mail as well and I can send e-mails from there just fine

Comment: IIRC Gmail uses SSL, hence you need `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` or `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`

Comment: that was what i suggested in the answer... He has to change the host as i suggest too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "**********";
$mail->Port = "465";
```

That is a working configuration.

try to replace what you have

Comment: Thanks ybert,

This actually pointed me in the right direction and it's now fixed!

I'm 99.999% sure I had the exact same config failing earlier, but maybe it's a combination of what's been changed at the backend since.

I had to add `$address = "myOtherEmail@me.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "James Cushing");
$message = "Email body";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
 
if(!$mail->Send()) {
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
 echo "Message sent!";
}`

But after that it worked locally. Testing on my web server now

Comment: Ok, running it on my web server still gives me **SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)**

We're half way there though!

Comment: It is an other error. Your SMTP server on your webserver is not well configured. But the code is good . You don't have to change it!

Comment: I think the error is that your port '465' is blocked on your server. You have to fix it.

Comment: James, I think ybert is right.  Try opening a telnet connection from your server to smtp.gmail.com on port 465.  Does it connect?

Comment: I think you were not specifically setting $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; to ssl, some

Comment: You may use str_rot13() for the password.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use SSL on port 465, it's been deprecated since 1998 and is only used by Microsoft products that didn't get the memo; use TLS on port 587 instead: So, the code below should work very well for you.

```
mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the
```

Comment: If using a specific web host though, some have 465 as the default port.

Comment: Their support should be able to give you a walk around.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, use these settings for Google:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; //edited from tsl
$mail->Username = "myEmail";
$mail->Password = "myPassword";
$mail->Port = "587";
```

But also, what firewall have you got set up?

If you're filtering out TCP ports 465/995, and maybe 587, you'll need to configure some exceptions or take them off your rules list.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: $mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl"; should be $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar failure with SMTP whenever my client machine changes network connection (e.g., home vs. office network) and somehow restarting network service (or rebooting the machine) resolves the issue for me. Not sure if this would apply to your case, but just in case.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart   # for ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Google created the "use less secure accounts method" function:

https://myaccount.google.com/security

Then created the another permission:

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was a problem from about 4 years ago, but hopefully someone searching for the same issue will find this helpful :)

Comment: Thanks. I think so too. :)