# Why isn't my PHP email working?

Tags: php, email

I've worked on this for hours. Seriously very frustrated. I don't know code at all and in serious need of help.

I am trying to get an email automatically sent as users reach a particular point in a website. 
But everything I've tried says error 500. 
so I am currently following numerous tutorials that suggest downloading this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. 
Which I've done, including uploading it to my host and nothing occurs.

Please if anyone can help, I seriously don't know code at all so examples only, please.

```
<?php
    require_once ('../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

    $mail= new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSTMP();
    $mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';
    $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port='465';
    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@eves.website')
    $mail->Subject='Hello World';
    $mail->Body='A test email!';
    $mail->AddAddress('brodisashcroft@gmail.com');

    $mail-> Send ();

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message you are getting?

Comment: @drum "This page isn’t working
www.eves.website is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Does PHPMailer actually exist one directory up from where this file is located? If not, your very first line `require_once()` is failing to include the PHPMailerAutoload file.

Comment: It's not a good idea to publish valid email addresses, since spammers could use them to send junk mail. Now, as @drum suggested, please post the error message, if it's not displayed in the web page, you need to search the exact text in the error log.

Comment: Which version did you download? Why are you not using composer?

Comment: I've tried both the master and the 5.2 @LawrenceCherone

Comment: @Triby this is exclusively for a one time assignment, these emails will never be used again, except for the presentation of the website to my lecture

Comment: Your need https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/v5.2.26 or your open yourself to like 15 vulnerabilities .. but you should use composer and use the latest version.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't know what a composer is, very new to this

Comment: @PatrickMoore Yes it is one directory up

Comment: Your not trying to send a smtp mail to yourself from yourself are you?  Because that doesn't work in gmail over smtp.  Or at least it didn't when I set up my SMTP mail, (like 4 years ago)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix no two separate emails

Comment: Ok, because I tried for like 5 hours then i sent it to another account by accident and behold it worked. lol, but as I said that was 4 years ago, also I only use it on local host because I'm to lazy to setup a test email server ... lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix If only that was the case here, I did set up a test email and still nothing

Comment: Email is a fickle thing, did you check your spam folder?

Comment: Have you set username and password? Coz I don't see that in your script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535294/mail-not-sending-with-phpmailer-over-ssl-using-smtp

Comment: Also, according to your error, please check your dns settings for eves.website coz it has an MX error: https://intodns.com/eves.website

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon here:

```
$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@eves.website')
```

At the end of the line:

```
$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@eves.website');
```

Comment: Ugh that gave me so much hope! But after editing it to include the semicolon, still nothing is appearing.