# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) when using phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, centos7

This works perfectly in my old server.

2020-07-18 16:37:45 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
I am now using CentOS 7 and php7.3.2

What I've tried.

- use port 587,465,25
- use host smtp.gmail.com,108.177.122.108

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $randompassword = generateRandomString();
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        $connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $insertSql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, forgot) VALUES ('$name', '$randompassword', '$email', 1)";
        $status = $connect->query($insertSql);
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'username@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = '*******';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
        $mail->Charset    = "UTF-8";
        $mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress($email);               // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo('to@gmail.com', 'to');                                 // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'body'
        $mail->send();
        echo '<script>alert("already send");</script>'; 
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<script>alert('error');</script>";
        echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available";
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

I test telnet smtp.gmail.com for port 25 465 587,the result is also connection time out.Then I test on my computer gets a normal result.

Comment: Not a php problem, but a network problem...

Comment: Perhaps your configuration should look more like this for SSL? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18535449/1526322

Comment: Why are you using an IP address instead of `smtp.gmail.com`?

Comment: I said I tried both of them at the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using a Linode Server, they blocked port 25, 465, 587, so I can't send mail and telnet smtp.gmail.com.
[for more infomation, ckick here.](https://www.linode.com/blog/linode/a-new-policy-to-help-fight-spam/)

Comment: Did they enable them for you?

Answer (score 0):

Network problem. Firewall is blocking those ports. Surprised it's blocking the SSL port as well. Once you resolve that, you should be good to go. As an alternative, you could change the port on the SMTP server to a custom port that your provider will allow you to use (25000, 25252, etc).