# Hostgator send mail

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using the following code to send email from my website:

```
<?php

$to = "mygmail@gmail.com;
$subject = "My Site - NoReply";
$headers = "From: do not reply @ My Site" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "You have received a message from the My site: <br /><br />";
$message .= "Greetings <strong>My Name</strong>, <br /><br />";
$message .= "You have been granted access to the My site.<br /><br />";
                    
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

My site is being hosted by Hostgator.  They have advised me that I should use port 465 for SMTP.

I just finished chatting with them.  Everything is set on their end, and there is nothing additional that they can do.

With that said, why am I unable to send the email using the above?

I've used this same code on my job, which uses an Apache server, and I have no problems sending any email from a website.

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: this question may contain some insights https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535294/mail-not-sending-with-phpmailer-over-ssl-using-smtp

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem here is that **you're not using SMTP**.

PHP's `mail()` function works by submitting a message to a `sendmail` binary via a shell, and does not use the network directly at all, so you have no way of doing what they asked.

Sending through SMTP, even to localhost, is preferable to using `mail()` because it's faster, safer, and more reliable.

You tagged this question with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), which *can* send through SMTP directly, and @j4g0 provided a link to a reasonable implementation of that. There are many more examples both here on SO and in the PHPMailer project.